# Trying to Replace CSS transition with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I'm working on a nav menu that has a full screen width drop down sub-menu. I'm using CSS transitions to animate the drop down. It works beautifully in FF and Chrome, but it doesn't work in older versions of IE. Therefore, I'm looking for a jQuery solution that can replace this bit of code:

```
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

Specifically, I'm looking for a way to use jQuery to have the sub-menu slidedown (and fade in at the same time if possible) when the top level links are hovered over.  Can anybody help?  Here is a working fiddle using CSS transitions showing the effect I want to achieve with jQuery: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/halosinfire/rJdsd/4/) Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

it is a very useful jquery plug-in

Comment: The documentation says: "Transit degrades older browsers by simply not doing the transformations (rotate, scale, etc) while still doing standard CSS (opacity, marginLeft, etc) without any animation. Delays and durations will be ignored."  

I think this means that I'll still be left with the same problem - no animation in older versions of IE.